# How to make duet video like smule

Tags: bash, shell, animation, video, ffmpeg

I need to create duet video from two video with animation like Smule
Ex: https://www.smule.com/p/449637376_741981684
Anyone know how to create like this? 
I also use ffmpeg for create duet video but I don't know how to create animation??
My ffmpeg command:

```
 ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 -i v2.mp4 -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=360x480[base]; \
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0[left]; \
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x480, crop=180:480:90:0 [right]; \
[base][left] overlay=x=0:y=0[base1]; \
[base1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=180:y=0" -c:v libx264 -y result.mp4
```

Comment: This is a brand new singing plataform project which is beggining - LiveJam. https://github.com/richardaum/livejam 
Take a look and consider support us - we are looking expert contributors and you could be one of us.